# iPhone Facebook SDK - Upload Photo from your App to Facebook

Tags: iphone, ios5, facebook

Since the Facebook SDK change every hours it's hard to get an actual tutorial that works with the current SDK version.. some change are radical!!!

I'm trying to upload a photo... but the PROBLEM is my FBSessionDelegate Methods "fbDidLogin" is never called. I log on, get back to the app, but nothing happen :/

I guess there's a problem with my Session Delegate :/

The main change in this new SDK is about the Delegate... you set the delegate once in the view did load instead of setting it [facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];

Ive tried with a Video (tutorial) found : http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/532/

**That is my .H**

```
#import "Facebook.h"

@interface sampleClass : UIViewController 
                             <FBSessionDelegate, FBRequestDelegate> {

    Facebook * facebook;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) Facebook * facebook;

- (IBAction)uploadPhoto:(id)sender;
```

**And this is my .M**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kAppId andDelegate:self];
}

- (IBAction)uploadPhoto:(id)sender {

     NSArray* permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"offline_access", @"publish_stream", nil];

    [facebook authorize:permissions];

}

#pragma mark - Facebook Session Delegate Methods

- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"mov"];
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               videoData, @"video.mov",
                               @"video/quicktime", @"contentType",
                               @"Video Test Title", @"title",
                               @"Video Test Description", @"description",
                               nil];
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                     andParams:params
                 andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                   andDelegate:self];
}

-(void)fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled {
NSLog(@"did not login");
}


#pragma mark - Facebook Request Delegate Methods

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    result = [result objectAtIndex:0];
}
NSLog(@"Result of API call: %@", result);
}

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Failed with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}



#pragma mark - Support SSO for Facebook


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [self.facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put in your Application Delegate.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
```

and put 'Facebook *facebook' variable at a place where it can be access by both Application Delegate and your View Controller.

You can follow this guide for further clarification

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#implementsso

Answer (score 0):

Did you get it working?  Did you try using Hackbook for an example?  It's in the sdk download as an example.  This link is referring to Demo App, but it's called Hackbook now.  http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/how-to-develop-facebook-application-for-iphone/

Mich

Comment: Yes I got it ! But I had to use another way ! Now I'am sharing the photo as a photo album for the application, so facebook let me upload the photo on facebook album, instead of sharing an "article" which I could do that, but I would have to upload my image on a FTP then link the image as the showing picture.  Understand ? :P